# Creating a pandas column from a dictionary of regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a column which essentially shows the data type of the data within an excel spreadsheet, i.e. if the data within any given cell is a string or an integer or a float etc. Currently I'm working with mocked up data to test with and hope to eventually use this for larger excel files with more field headers.

My Current high level method is as follows:

1. Read Excel file and create a dataframe
2. Re-format this table to create a column of all data I wish to label with a data type (i.e if it is a string, integer or float), alongside the respective field headers.
3. Create a 'Data Type' column which will contain these labels for each piece of data which is populated by the corresponding data types held in a dictionary of regular expressions

```
import os
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
from os import path
import re

sample_file = 'C:/Users/951297/Documents/Python Scripts/DD\\Fund_Data.xlsx'

dataf = pd.read_excel(sample_file)
dataf

    FUND ID     FUND NAME              AMOUNT
0   10101       Holdings company A     10000
1   20202       Holdings company B     2000.5
2   30303       Holdings company C     3000
```

```
# Create column list of data attributes
stackdf= dataf.stack().reset_index()
stackdf = stackdf.rename(columns={'level_0':'index','level_1':'fh',0:'attribute'})

# Create a duplicate column of attribute to apply regex
stackdf_regex = stackdf.iloc[:,2:].rename(columns = {'attribute':'Data Type'})

# Dictionary of regex to replace values within the 'Data Type' column depending on the attribute
repl_dict = {re.compile(r'^[\d]+$'):'Integer',
             re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$'): 'String',
             re.compile(r'[\d]+\.'): 'Float'}

#concatenate tables
pd.concat([stackdf, stackdf_regex], axis=1)
```

This is the reformatted table I wish to apply my regular expressions onto:

```
   index    fh          attribute                Data Type
0   0      FUND ID      10101                    10101
1   0      FUND NAME    Holdings company A       Holdings company A
2   0      AMOUNT       10000                    10000
3   1      FUND ID      20202                    20202
4   1      FUND NAME    Holdings company B       Holdings company B
5   1      AMOUNT       2000.5                   2000.5
6   2      FUND ID      30303                    30303
7   2      FUND NAME    Holdings company C       Holdings company C
8   2      AMOUNT       3000                     3000
```

This is the desired output:

```
   index    fh          attribute                Data Type
0   0      FUND ID      10101                    Integer
1   0      FUND NAME    Holdings company A       String
2   0      AMOUNT       10000                    Integer
3   1      FUND ID      20202                    Integer
4   1      FUND NAME    Holdings company B       String
5   1      AMOUNT       2000.5                   Float
6   2      FUND ID      30303                    Integer
7   2      FUND NAME    Holdings company C       String
8   2      AMOUNT       3000                     Integer
```

However the following code produces the table below:

```
stackdf_regex = stackdf_regex.replace({'Data Type':repl_dict}, regex=True)
pd.concat([stackdf, stackdf_regex], axis=1)

  index     fh          attribute             Data Type
0   0       FUND ID     10101                 10101
1   0       FUND NAME   Holdings company A    String
2   0       AMOUNT      10000                 10000
3   1       FUND ID     20202                 20202
4   1       FUND NAME   Holdings company B    String
5   1       AMOUNT      2000.5                2000.5
6   2       FUND ID     30303                 30303
7   2       FUND NAME   Holdings company C    String
8   2       AMOUNT      3000                  3000
```

Perhaps my regular expressions are incorrect or my understanding is lacking in applying the regular expressions on the dataframe. Happy to receive any suggestions on this current method or another suitable/efficient method I have not considered.

Note: I hope to eventually expand the regex dictionary to account for more data types and I understand it may not be efficient to check every cell for a pattern for larger datasets but I'm still in the early stages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), where each of the `conditions` test a given regex to the column `Data Type` using [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and `choices` corresponds to the conditions:

```
conditions = [
    df['Data Type'].str.contains(r'^\d+$'), 
    df['Data Type'].str.contains(r'^[\w\s]+$'), 
    df['Data Type'].str.contains(r'^\d+\.\d+$')]

choices = ['Interger', 'String', 'Float']

df['Data Type'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=None)
```

---

```
# print(df)
   index         fh           attribute Data Type
0      0    FUND ID               10101  Interger
1      0  FUND NAME  Holdings company A    String
2      0     AMOUNT               10000  Interger
3      1    FUND ID               20202  Interger
4      1  FUND NAME  Holdings company B    String
5      1     AMOUNT              2000.5     Float
6      2    FUND ID               30303  Interger
7      2  FUND NAME  Holdings company C    String
8      2     AMOUNT                3000  Interger
```